# Robot Framework with Node.js for testing network protocols

Tags: node.js, robotframework

I've searched alot about this subject that was assigned to me, that is testing some network protocols like DNS, DHCP, ARP, UPnP and so on.

Since I cant find a framework that gives a report like Robot Framework, I came here to ask if it's possible to use node.js and robot framework together for those kind of tests.

All examples that I've found are about webservers, and that it's not what I'am looking for.

EDIT:
Also open to other framework suggestions.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Robotframework can be used to test anything that you can do from the python programming language (which is a *lot*). You also can have tests that run .NET or Java code to connect to your servers.

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunely there aren't any usage examples with node.js without being about webservers, and creating a remote server. I've tested it with Jython for java code, but right now i need it for node.

Answer (score 0):

You might try [rammbock](https://github.com/robotframework/Rammbock) that is a protocol testing library for robot framework. There's at least one example for [DNS](https://github.com/robotframework/Rammbock/blob/master/atest/dns/dns.txt).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [robotremote](https://github.com/comick/node-robotremoteserver) (I'm the author) Robot Remote Server for nodejs.
A remote server is still a good choice. One possibility is to run the remote server when the test suite starts and shut it down on tear-down.

Robot Framework offers a [Remote library interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#remote-library-interface) in a way that a library can be a remote service providing keywords. Such remote service is provided by an implementation of a Robot Remote Server which is a small wrapper around an XML-RPC based protocol that you can use to expose keywords to a Robot Framework test runner in complex deployments.